# React useState hook returns old state value despite it being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I want to:

1. upload an image into the browser (I do this with React Dropzone. My `uploadImage` function below runs onDrop of file into Dropzone.)
2. read the image as an actual image using the FileReader API.
3. save the image file as well as image metadata into state, using React Hooks.
4. make an API call that pushes this image to a server.

I am trying to confirm that I have the image at step 4, but I cannot confirm that via my console messages. I'm somehow stuck with the original state values despite log messages showing the state has already been updated.

I've tried adding extra asyncs to everything, and I've wrapped stuff in promises. I can confirm the `readImage` function is fine. I can confirm the run sequence is `readImage`, `saveImage`, `setGraphic` within saveImage, and then the console.log in `uploadImage` which should have the updated values but doesn't.

```
  const [graphic, setGraphic] = useState({ ...nullGraphic });

  const readImage = async (img) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.onerror = () => reader.abort();
      reader.onabort = () => reject(new DOMException('Problem parsing input file.'));
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    });
  };

  const saveImage = async (img) => {
    const imageRead = await readImage(img);

    console.log(imageRead);

    await setGraphic({
      ...graphic,
      image: imageRead,
      imageName: img.name,
      imageType: img.type,
    });

  };


  const uploadImage = async (img) => {
    await saveImage(img);

    console.log(graphic);
});

render() {

  console.log(graphic);

  return( <some dom> )
}
```

this is my strange console sequence:

```
Form.js:112 starting saveImage 
Form.js:95 (snipped value of imageRead)
Form.js:237 {snipped updated values of graphic}
Form.js:114 done with saveImage
Form.js:116 {snipped original values of graphic}
```

My Theory

The useState hook is doing something funky.
The process copies the value when it starts instead of reading it whenever the console.log is being read, so the `uploadImage` function gets the original values of the useState hook for the lifetime of that process.

Comment: What makes you think you can `await setGraphic`?

Comment: I assumed it would return a promise. Even if it doesn't, I've also tried wrapping it in a promise, and nothing changed.

I don't think that's the problem though because it clearly *is* updating the state in the order that I want it to. It's the reading of the state that is out of order.

Comment: `setState` is flushed in batches meaning it's asynchronous, but it doesn't return a promise thus you can't `await` it. if you `console.log` the next state just after you call `setState`you won't log the updated state because of it's async nature.

Comment: If you are using hooks this means this is a functional component, why do you have a render method, shouldnt you just return JSX directly and have the console.log statement inside the JSX?

Comment: @iqbal125 You're right, there was no render method. I was trying to construct a simplified version of the component I was working on, and I messed up in that part.

Answer (score 1):

It might become clear why this would not work if we would simplify all those React magic into :

```
  function withState(initial, fn) {
    function setState(updated) {
       setTimeout(() => fn(updated, setState), 0);
       //...
    }
    setState(initial);
  }
```

Now we can illustrate what happens:

```
  withState(0, (counter, setCount) => {
    console.log("before", counter);
    if(counter < 10) setCount(counter + 1);
    console.log("after", counter);
  });
```

As you can see, `setCount` will not change the state (`count`) directly. It will actually not change the local `count` variable at all. Therefore "before" and "after" will always log the same (as long as you don't mutate `counter` directly).

Instead calling `setCount` will be deffered (and batched in React), and then it will *recall* the whole component function passing in the new count.

Therefore it makes no sense trying to `await` the setState call, also it makes no sense to log the state before and after it (as it won't change inbetween). Log it once in a component, if you set the state the whole component executes again and the logging will log the new state.

Comment: It's helping that you have pointed out these errors, but what I am missing is the larger answer still. Is the broad concept of what I was trying to do possible without having to put everything into a single function?

I also don't understand where the React magic function came from. How did you construct that?